# Keyvaluepair value issue appsettings

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

This is my appsettings

```
  {
    "Messages": {
        "ApiUrl": "demo",   
        "ApiKey": {
          "Key": "key",
          "Value": "1234"
        }
    }
  }
```

**Model Class:**

```
public class CPSSettings
{
    public Messages Messages { get; set; } = null!;  
}
public class Messages
{
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; } = null!;
    public KeyValuePair<string?, string?> ApiKey{ get; set; }
}
```

I am not getting values for `_settings.Messages.ApiKey.Key` and `_settings.Messages.ApiKey.Value`

But receiving value for `ApiUrl`. I have issue with KeyValuePair not receiving a value

```
public testClient(IOptions<CPSSettings> options)
{  
    _settings = options.Value;
}

//...

if (_settings.Messages.ApiKey.Key is not null 
    && _settings.Messages.ApiKey.Value is not null)
{
    var s = _settings.Messages.ApiKey.Key;    // am getting null vaues in both
    var s1 = _settings.Messages.ApiKey.Value
}
```

Comment: Your code seems confused. Your settings file has `ApiKey`; your `Messages` class has `UserId`; but the code that access it has `ApiKey`.

Comment: I can' t see where you define and assign settings. Can you post it pls?

Comment: @RichardDeeming sory i haave updated..i have removed some codes in class...pls check updated question

Comment: @Serge value is coming for ApiUrl and ApiKey keyvaluepair type..so it is coming nul

Comment: @Ajt I am asking where settings variable  is coming from?

Comment: i am injecting in constructor..updated in the question

Comment: @Ajt The members of [KeyValuePair](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/KeyValuePair.cs,34) are **readonly**. The framework is unable to set those values after initializing the struct

Comment: @Nkosi thanks you is there any alternative..pls let me know in the answer

Comment: @Ajt use another object type that you control. that has modifiable members

Comment: Thank you. very much @Nkosi...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members of [KeyValuePair](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/KeyValuePair.cs,34) are **readonly**. The framework is unable to set those values after initializing the struct

I would suggest you use another object type that you control. One that has modifiable members.

For example

```
public class CPSSettings {
    public Messages Messages { get; set; } = null!;  
}

public class Messages {
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; } = null!;
    public ApiKey ApiKey{ get; set; } //<-- NOTE THE CHANGE
} 

public class ApiKey {
    public string? Key { get; set; }
    public string? Value { get; set; }
}
```

That way, when binding the settings, the framework can initialize and properly set the values of the members

Answer (score 1):

Removing `CPSSettings` would simplify the scenario. **See below for how to access configuration values, via [Options pattern in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options), using `Messages`:**

1. Ensure you have registered `Messages` within `Startup.ConfigureServices(...)` (example below).

```cs
services.Configure<Messages>(Configuration.GetSection("Messages"));
```

2. Receive `IOptions<Messages>` as `testClient` constructor parameter (example below).

```
public testClient(IOptions<Messages> options)
{
    _settings = options.Value;
}
```

Comment: i have updated in the question...actually keyvaluepair is showing null

Comment: @Ajt, I've updated the answer to consider the additional question details.

Answer (score 1):

The members of KeyValuePair are readonly. You can use it but you will have to make some convertion.  I don' t think that your really need it. So I created another class to replace it. Also you have to  use Messages class to deseserialize settings. Class CPSSettings is a bug, you don't need it. So try this code, it was tested in Visual Studio.

```
var cpsSettingsSection = configuration.GetSection("Messages");
var cpsSettings = cpsSettingsSection.Get<Messages>();

var url = cpsSettings.ApiUrl;
var key = cpsSettings.ApiKey.Key.Dump();    
var value = cpsSettings.ApiKey.Value.Dump();

//services.Configure<Messages>(cpsSettingsSection);

public class Messages
{
    public string ApiUrl { get; set; }
    public KeyValueString ApiKey {get; set;}
 }

public class KeyValueString
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```